# How to modify (TableLayout margin's embeded in Relativelay out in xml) in code

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-relativelayout

i have main.xml :

```
     <? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/detailsback">    
  >

<TextView  
android:id="@+id/name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="30px"
android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
/>

<EditText  
android:id="@+id/ed"
android:layout_width="200px" 
android:layout_height="200px"
android:editable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:text="ddddddddddd"
android:layout_below="@id/name"
/>

<TableLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
 >

<TableRow>    

  <Button  
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="50px" 
android:layout_height="50px" 
android:layout_marginRight="15px"
/>

    <Button  
android:id="@+id/btn2"
android:layout_width="40px" 
android:layout_height="50px"  
android:layout_marginRight="15px"
/>

      <Button  
android:id="@+id/btn3"
android:layout_width="100px" 
android:layout_height="20px" 
android:layout_marginRight="15px"
/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>    

   <Button  
android:id="@+id/btn4"
android:layout_width="50px" 
android:layout_height="50px"  
android:layout_marginRight="15px"
android:layout_marginTop="5px"
/>

<Button  
android:id="@+id/btn5"
android:layout_width="30px" 
android:layout_height="50px"  
android:layout_marginRight="15px"
android:layout_marginTop="5px"    
/>
  <Button  
android:id="@+id/btn6"
android:layout_width="100px" 
android:layout_height="20px"  
android:layout_marginRight="15px"
android:layout_marginTop="5px"
/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in the code i used

```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

now i  want to modify  TableLayout margin's according to screen resolution , the problem is how to reach to TableLayout via code , i tried this :

```
TableLayout table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    LayoutParams pa=new LayoutParams();
    pa.bottomMargin=20;
    pa.rightMargin=20;

    table.setLayoutParams(pa);
```

but it don't work !!

Comment: What is the need to add these margins out of curiousity?  why not set them in layout xml?

Comment: caz i want to change them with the changing of screen width & height with carious devices

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem, and I figured it out by below method,

try to change the line

```
LayoutParams pa=new LayoutParams();
```

to

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams pa= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```